# My photo upload script is not working in php

Tags: php

```
<?php include('header.php');
include ('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit_image'])){
  $imgname=$_FILES["myimage"]["name"] ;
    $target="ProfileImages/";
    $filetarget=$target.$imgname;
    $tempname=$_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"];

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tempname,$filetarget);
    if($result){

        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $caption=$_POST['caption'];
        $q="INSERT into `images` (id,path,caption) VALUES ('$id','$filetarget','$caption')";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
        if($res)
        {
            $msg="Photo Uploaded Sucessfully..";
            $_SESSION['msg']=$msg;
            header('location:profile.php');
        }
    }
    else{

        $msg="Error Not Uploaded...Try Again";
            $_SESSION['msg']=$msg;
            header('location:profile.php');
        }
}
?>        
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <h2><u>Select Image</u></h2><br><input type="file" name="myimage"><br>
<h2><u>Caption</u></h2><br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="25" name="caption"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload">
</form>
```

### Heading

I was trying to upload pictures through this code, but after some time I checked it was not working...Can any of you help me how to fix this?

Comment: What part of it is not working? What have you tried? Do the logs give anything? There isn't enough information to help adequately.

Comment: can you add the `html` for the upload `form` ?

Comment: what done this code ?

Comment: @Taki Please take a look i've added HTML part now.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: What is actually happening? "Error Not Uploaded...Try Again" or something else?

Comment: Error not Uploaded...it is not moving the files, but the `$filetarget` is valid filename.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the [PHP Error Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)!

Isolate the working script and try to find out where the issue is. Make sure if:

1. the parser enters the first `if`
2. is the `$filetarget` valid file name
3. was the file move successful
4. was the query successful
5. is the redirection to valid page

If you do not have debugger, disable the `header('location:profile.php');` to stay on the page and see errors and/or print testing messages such as `echo "I am here on line ".__LINE__;` to make sure the parser is in.

Comment: No, it is not like that I have a separate table where `id` is the foreign key and I am inserting the multiple images for the single user who is logged in ...Before some time code was working fine...Don't know what happened now??

Comment: @saksham7 - If you want us to have a chance of figure it out and be able to help you, you need to, at least, check your log files to see if you get any error messages.

Comment: Yes i have enabled it in php.ini

Comment: Just to be sure, enable it in the script as well.

Comment: I have updated my original answer with couple of hints. Hope this will help you to find the direction to solve your `it was not working` issue.

Comment: @ino yes, I have figured it out that function `move_uploaded_file()` is not working..

Comment: Great! So you have found the problem and got it fixed. If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)